# In Angular, is there a way to have app level toolbar but not have it in pages like login, registration?

Tags: angular, performance, toolbar

I'm an Angular beginner. I'm trying to get the best performing Login page for my app. I don't want to go into Angular Universal yet. (read somewhere that it only helps in reducing the FCP but not the FMP).

Anyways, I have a toolbar in app component with an ngIf. Because it's in app component, I cannot lazy load the toolbar related JavaScript. So, although the application doesn't need the toolbar until after the user logged in, it still downloads the necessary JS/CSS/HTML files. This makes the initial page load slower. I investigated into possible solutions.

1. Add the toolbar in all the feature modules (Possibly a bad solution).
2. Have a parent component at "/home" which only has toolbar and load the remaining pages as child components. (The issue with this approach is all my routes have "home/" in them.)

Any other solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: hi @Kishan Dasari what you have tried so far ? I think once you have to look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-ngif may be it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to achieve this.
first your can use *ngIf but i will not suggest this to you the second option is that create two modules one will be auth.module for login and register and second will be pages.module which will have all other components which contain the toolbar both components will have their own views pages comonents will have the toolbar and auth component will have anything you want to add in it. remove everything from the app component except  and add routing files for those modules as well